# How can I do a dual axis using highcharter library?

Tags: r, highcharts

someone could tell what command I should add to get a dual axis in one graphic.

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyr)
base1=gather(base1,"serie","valor",2:4)
p1<-base1 %>% hchart("line",hcaes(x = Año,y=valor, group=serie)) %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_economist())
p1
# Gráfica 2
dir(pattern="*.xlsx")
library(readxl)
base1=read_xlsx("DatosColombia.xlsx", sheet = "Hoja3")
attach(base1)

library(highcharter)
library(tidyr)
base1=gather(base1,"serie","valor",2:3)
p2<-base1 %>% hchart("line",hcaes(x = Año,y=valor, group=serie)) %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_economist())
p2
```

Comment: Could you provide a `dput` of your data?!

Answer (score 0):

Use hc_yAxis_multiples

Basic example:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(lineWidth = 3),
    list(showLastLabel = FALSE, opposite = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = rnorm(10)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = rexp(10), type = "spline", yAxis = 1)
```